# Stuck in window.close() javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that is stuck in closing the browser tab. This is the code I supplied.

```html
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/jpg" 
      href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YgzPv8NQgVPI1DY5yP_ID1-r1_3B6D6IhMw6OBbIyR_wISEtDe6AbljpX1qxUS6KK9Es2CQ1uE3dAlMzLhp5gx5Gh1D4_Rsp2FydHPuJbWn-5g7DBWKOHGOrsvVHumU49WY3k7vT_ICzsAzqfetP2zfd1vkGMG6O3WJZzY_9sVWwm-ZywoDPJ6Qxpf8fbh0ow8BYkIHT2BCgFWDk-nn-SJZbixxpb7OA9QdJyIyWr-fzffl46Ww2MZx4rMC5-9ImSzv_ZTgKB89i3fflrAR0063ADUE4NmJzSqnf3wuaQwDZjEkJalovEckyO5brf_5o_nwTfhZUElDF_asrHvHgF1ptq4XIzECTebeNrhzqQkIcKCpA0hD4b6TZ1nxcmc65K4UrzvuWWlHyfW5adzqJNwlByA9tWTNCHWPmLD2FUud0bywUSgvAS31noRh8GLlKH2ln5nbNMCY8CnN6c6OBZR6fS0nQ0a4bbzztxzkJX-3JwkwKocBlz9PMP_fFYrffd_R8OQJOSEfkHbOHP8wdFuS9ds-YOJ7oLtNxl4CRZP4kwDOywrUSXXja8XEU4mSZJb3UHiAprYnz-t-yfqm7Y9isJn22YMMgU8hjIufV20ckdcOi8vER90F8TeGjj6XWmKEtuwO_lONYr9t5-unKalapbHfr-D-UVms9AACfNB_Co9jXdzTWDa2_GJ_tQoLoqzr0C7178u5705QmNCqG__c=w708-h853-no?authuser=0">
<h1>Logon</h1>
<button onclick="SignIn()">Sign In</button>


<script>
    function SignIn()  {
        var a=prompt("Enter your UserPass.");
        var b=prompt("Enter your ID Number.");

        if (a=="adminuser" && b=="pass") {
            alert("Welcome We logged you in.");
            window.location.href("http://{admin-page}.imango.com.au")

        }
         else

            alert("We could not log you in with the supplied details. Please try again later.");
    }
</script>
```

I cannot seem to stop it from closing the webpage after the prompts.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Tha main issue I see in your code is that you're using `href` as a function: it's not, it's a property on `location`. So it should be: `window.location.href = "http://{admin-page}.imango.com.au"`

Comment: You don't seem to have your window.close() function, href is not a function use like this:
 window.location.href = "http://{admin-page}.imango.com.au"

Comment: Oh wait it was actually the cookies messing me up

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, `Window.location.href` is not a function, it's a property, which provides us the current location or you could assign a location to it.
Instead of this you could use `Window.location.assign("http://{adminpage}.imango.com.au");` to redirect the user to the different page.

Also please add `Window.close()` to close your screen.

Comment: Window.location.href is not a variable , please use words wisely.

Comment: @Shubhra Kushal  I used the window.close() function earlier and later changed it to redirect my users and it kept closing the window after

Comment: everyone. I do not want to close the window.

Comment: This is the page that is having problems. imango.com.au/adminccg.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/jpg" 
      href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YgzPv8NQgVPI1DY5yP_ID1-r1_3B6D6IhMw6OBbIyR_wISEtDe6AbljpX1qxUS6KK9Es2CQ1uE3dAlMzLhp5gx5Gh1D4_Rsp2FydHPuJbWn-5g7DBWKOHGOrsvVHumU49WY3k7vT_ICzsAzqfetP2zfd1vkGMG6O3WJZzY_9sVWwm-ZywoDPJ6Qxpf8fbh0ow8BYkIHT2BCgFWDk-nn-SJZbixxpb7OA9QdJyIyWr-fzffl46Ww2MZx4rMC5-9ImSzv_ZTgKB89i3fflrAR0063ADUE4NmJzSqnf3wuaQwDZjEkJalovEckyO5brf_5o_nwTfhZUElDF_asrHvHgF1ptq4XIzECTebeNrhzqQkIcKCpA0hD4b6TZ1nxcmc65K4UrzvuWWlHyfW5adzqJNwlByA9tWTNCHWPmLD2FUud0bywUSgvAS31noRh8GLlKH2ln5nbNMCY8CnN6c6OBZR6fS0nQ0a4bbzztxzkJX-3JwkwKocBlz9PMP_fFYrffd_R8OQJOSEfkHbOHP8wdFuS9ds-YOJ7oLtNxl4CRZP4kwDOywrUSXXja8XEU4mSZJb3UHiAprYnz-t-yfqm7Y9isJn22YMMgU8hjIufV20ckdcOi8vER90F8TeGjj6XWmKEtuwO_lONYr9t5-unKalapbHfr-D-UVms9AACfNB_Co9jXdzTWDa2_GJ_tQoLoqzr0C7178u5705QmNCqG__c=w708-h853-no?authuser=0">
<h1>Logon</h1>
<button onclick="SignIn()">Sign In</button>


<script>
    function SignIn()  {
        var a=prompt("Enter your UserPass.");
        var b=prompt("Enter your ID Number.");

        if (a=="adminuser" && b=="pass") {
            alert("Welcome We logged you in.");
            window.location.href=`http://${admin-page}.imango.com.au`
```

> I have used backtick to include the variable admin-page

```
        }
         else

            alert("We could not log you in with the supplied details. Please try again later.");
    }
</script>
```